# React Semantic UI - where documentation on form validation?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have implemented some form validation in React Semantic UI based on some posts I found on SO - for example, the following:

```
     required={true}
     error={this.state.errors["macs"]}
```

My question is, where are these the React Semantic UI documentation? I haven't had any luck finding it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/ - specifically in the Form.Field prop.

[image: Semantic UI React Documentation]

[Field Variations Required Field](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#field-variations-required-field) shows required in use

[States Field Error Label](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-field-error-label) shows the Field with the error property set to show a message with a pointer.

[Form error state with Messages](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-error) shows a Message that displays when the form is in an error state.